# Moving Site From Development to Production

Tags: migration

I have a WordPress site at the root of a bluehost account ( inside public_html ) and there is an add-on domain also residing in a folder named devsite inside public_html. We have spent months developing the content in the devsite to be ready to promote to production.

On Saturday, I made a control panel snapshot and downloaded copies of both the current production site as well as the development site. Then I tried the upgrade.

The first way I tried was to use a tool called DesktopServer on my Mac to import the devsite. That worked. I then tried to deploy it to the production domain as per instructions but the deployment failed.

I restored the site via the snapshot.

On Sunday I tried the "WordPress" way of FTPing the files to public_html and exporting the database, fixing the links using "Search & Replace for Wordpress databases" and modifying the WP-Config to point to the new database. None of the pages on the site transferred, the menus didn't transfer, the widgets were not set ... in short, the promotion was a disaster.

Today, I tried the DesktopServer method on the Windows 7 machine at work. However, after making the site archive, DesktopServer reports that it is unable to locate the main index.php in the site archive but I checked and it is there.

I am out of ideas on how to move this site to production and would appreciate and guidance or help.

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: You need to make a more specific question, using FTP is straightforward, what do you mean by "None of the pages on the site transferred"?

Comment: All of the posts, events, users, etc transferred but none of the content pages (and there are many) transferred. The site went from having probably 80 content pages to a home page and a "sample page."

Comment: That still doesn't help, what is a content page? Did you verify that these pages were exported when you download the site, did you verify this data was uploaded?

Comment: The page templates are in the theme's wp-content folder. I don't know where WordPress store page data.

Comment: In the `wp-posts`'s table of the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Cpanel this is what I do. ***Ensure you have up to date backups of EVERYTHING before attempting to make changes to the database.***

First if Wordpress is installed on your production environment upload your theme files. (*sounds like you have done this already*)

Second go to Cpanel on your Development environment and select PHP MyAdmin.

- **Select the database** for the Wordpress install you have been working on.
- Then click on the **export** option at the top of the screen
- select the **custom** option for exporting your database
- select all of the tables **EXCEPT** for **wp_options**
- for the output select **save output to a file**
- scroll down to **Object Creation Options**
- **Check all three options** (*1. Add drop TABLE, 2. Add CREATE PROCEDURE and 3. CREATE TABLE options:* )
- Click **Go** (*this should download the export of your database.*)

Then, go to the cpanel for your production enviornment and select the PHP MyAdmin

- **Select the database** for the production installation of your Wordpress
  site
- Then **click on Import**.
- Broswe to **select your the database file** you downloaded.
- Click **Upload**.

Once the database has been uploaded you may need to go into the **dashboard > settings > permalinks**. Just loading this page will refresh your permalinks. No need to make any changes but there are times when I have seen a 404 error. Refreshing permalinks usually solves this problem for me.

Once you receive a success message after uploading make sure you go activate the theme in the admin area.

That has worked for me many times when I have had similar issues to the one you are having now.

Comment: how this doesn't have a hundred upvotes is beyond me. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I recently used [All-in-One WP Migration](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) By ServMask

Install on development site & production site.

For production site just create a basic WordPress install. Passwords and usernames will be overwritten.

This made things so very easy for me. You could try it out first from one development site to another.